# Twitter Python API in Terminal - Errors installing

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I've installed the following libraries and gotten through all the steps in the twitter python setup:

```
httplib2-0.7.1          simplegeo-python-oauth2-1fcc1a6
python-twitter-0.8.2        simplejson-2.1.6
```

I'm using the setup instructions here: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

When I run python setup.py test, I get 17 errors. Here is a snippet of the output (sorry it's a lot):

```
testNewFromJsonDict (twitter_test.UserTest)
Test the twitter.User NewFromJsonDict method ... ok
testProperties (twitter_test.UserTest)
Test all of the twitter.User properties ... ok
testCreateFriendship (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api CreateFriendship method ... ERROR
testDestroyDirectMessage (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api DestroyDirectMessage method ... ERROR
testDestroyFriendship (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api DestroyFriendship method ... ERROR
testDestroyStatus (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api DestroyStatus method ... ERROR
testGetDirectMessages (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetDirectMessages method ... ERROR
testGetFeatured (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetFeatured method ... ERROR
testGetFollowers (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetFollowers method ... ERROR
testGetFriends (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetFriends method ... ERROR
testGetFriendsTimeline (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetFriendsTimeline method ... ERROR
testGetPublicTimeline (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetPublicTimeline method ... ERROR
testGetReplies (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetReplies method ... ERROR
testGetStatus (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetStatus method ... ERROR
testGetUser (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetUser method ... ERROR
testGetUserTimeline (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api GetUserTimeline method ... ERROR
testPostDirectMessage (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api PostDirectMessage method ... ERROR
testPostUpdate (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test the twitter.Api PostUpdate method ... ERROR
testTwitterError (twitter_test.ApiTest)
Test that twitter responses containing an error message are wrapped. ... ERROR
```

Comment: well what errors are you getting? are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error messages that you omitted contains important information for troubleshooting. Let me guess - you downloaded the tar.gz file from the Downloads section of the project but it for some reason didn't package the test data in. So the reason of failure must be that it couldn't find the required testing data. You can see in its repository: http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/#hg%2Ftestdata

If this is true, don't panic. Just go on with your real world interaction with twitter API.

Comment: that seemed to have worked, but I also redownloaded from GitHub which fixed all the problems. Thanks!